# iPhone 6s not displaying names on text messages

Tags: ios, contacts, messages

I have a brand new iPhone 6s which suddenly stopped displaying names on text messages after I downloaded iOS 9.3. Any new ideas?

Comment: I've presumed you're on iOS 9.3 — please edit if this is incorrect. Furthermore, saying you've ‘tried many things’ doesn't help unless you state exactly what you've tried.

Answer (score 6):

I tried the answer above but that didn't work for me. After some trial and error turning off contacts in iCloud and then turning them back on worked for me.

1. Go to settings > iCloud
2. Turn off "Contacts" option
3. It will ask you if you want to delete the contacts synced on the phone or keep them. I deleted them.
4. Verify that the contacts are gone. (Optional)
5. Go back to the iCloud settings and turn the contacts on.

This worked for me. Took about a minute for all contacts to resolve in Messages app. I am on iOS 10.2 and this happened when my phone turned off unexpectedly due to battery issues.

Comment: I found that editing any contact from the messages app also reloads the contacts if all of the contacts are linked but names aren't showing. But I think you actually have to make a modification to the contact not just hit edit and save.

Answer (score 4):

None of the answers here worked for me. I had to:

1. Open the *Settings* app.
2. Scroll down to *Contacts*.
3. Tap the *Short Name* option.
4. Turn off the *Short Name* switch at the top.
5. Go to the home screen.
6. Open the *Settings* app.
7. Turn the *Short Name* option back on.

After that procedure, the Messages app on my iOS device once again showed names instead of phone numbers.

Comment: This did not work for me on iPhone 6 iOS 11.2.6.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Settings->Messages
2. Scroll down to the header SMS/MMS
3. Uncheck "MMS Messaging"
4. Restart iPhone
5. Go back to "MMS Messaging" and turn it on

This should fix the problem

Edit: This bug has been reported to Apple by many users under bug ID 22817380

Comment: This did not work for me on iPhone 6 iOS 11.2.6.