# "Maybe:" in front of Contacts on Message screen

Tags: iphone, messages, ios

I get a "Maybe:" in front of most iMessage contacts and only the phone number for SMS'es - even for persons from my contact list. What can be the cause and how can I solve it?

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/242649/265576

Comment: This is also related and helped me: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232176/iphone-6s-not-displaying-names-on-text-messages#comment337354_265342

Comment: Tap on the "i", then tap the name.  Scroll down and either add to existing contact or add a new contact.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Siri Suggestion feature that can be toggled off at Settings > Contacts > Siri & Search > toggle off "Find Contacts in Other Apps".

What is happening is that your device received a message or email from a number or address with a name that could be linked to it, e.g. an email from "John Smith " or a message from a new number that says something like "Hi, this is John Smith."

Comment: Any documentation for this feature? I've never heard of it.

Comment: It's been around since iOS 9. They've changed the wording and merged different features under the Siri brand, but it's been functionally similar since iOS 9. [This other post has information about it.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/242649/265576)